# Why don't the contour lines show up on this plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, contour

I'm trying to create a `contour` plot to show a height field at time 0, represented by `h_list[0, :, :]`. When I run the code, an empty plot shows up with the correct axes and scales, but no contour lines. The shape of `h_list` is [250, 99, 99], but I am only calling the first x index, which is shape [99, 99]. This matches the others.

My code is this:

```
h_list = np.array(h_list)

con = plt.figure()
ax = con.add_subplot(111)
x = np.linspace(0, 1000, 99)
y = np.linspace(0, 1000, 99)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = h_list[0, :, :]
ax.contour(X, Y, Z)

ax.set_xlim(0, 1000)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1000)
```

The shapes of all variables are the same and I've set the appropriate limits so I'm not sure why matplotlib isn't recognizing my data. I do not get any compiling errors, just no graph. Any ideas?

Edit: `Z` has shape [99, 99], which is the same as `X` and `Y`.

Comment: What does `Z` look like?

Comment: Added the shapes!

Comment: Not the shape, the actual values